# How do we edit the password meter in primereact?

Tags: primereact

anyone know how to edit the password meter from prime-react ? they only give like weak medium strong I need more than that. I haven't tried anything

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is that you cannot.  There are only 3 states `weak`, `medium` and `strong` and they have labels that can be updated if you don't like those terms you can use `weakLabel` etc to define your own text and your own regexes to determine strength.

See the properties available at the demo page: https://primefaces.org/primereact/password/